# Append data to json file

Tags: python, json

I have a .json file which looks like this for now:

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {"name" : "test"},
        {"name" : "test2"}
    ]
}
```

I want to append a line in Python directly after `{"name" : "test2}`.
Other questions I found will give me this solution:

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {"name" : "test"},
        {"name" : "test2"}
    ]
}{"name" : "test3"} # <-- Wrong place it shouldn't be here
```

This is what it should look like:

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {"name" : "test"},
        {"name" : "test2"},
        {"name" : "test3"}  # <-- new line here
    ]
}     # <-- not here
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking because you haven't shown those "other answers", or what code you tried. And "users" has a name; it's "users".

Comment: I mean a main-word for this. I want to say: "How to add new Items to the ..." the ... is the "users" and the items are the "{"name" : "test"}. I can't say which codes I tried because I tried many ones. The final thing was the second json code i posted, everytime.

Comment: Your desired effect on the `json` is not even valid, we're not sure what you're asking.

Comment: But why do you think it should have a name? It's just the "users" key of the dictionary, and you want to add another item to its list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yea "key" is the right word I guess. I want to add another Items in the "user" key / list.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply: parse your json to get a Python object, update the python object, and dump it back to json.

```
import json
with open("myfile.json") as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
obj["users"].append({"name":"was that so complicated, really ?"})
with open("myfile.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(f, obj)
```

I understand this might be a bit less obvious for a beginner, but given json specs, you can easily understand why the only **reliable** way to modify a json content is to actually parse it. Appending to the file won't work obviously as you already noticed (you'll get invalid json). Trying to read the file line by line, detect the end of the user array and insert a newline here won't work either (or only accidentally) since the json format does not mandate newlines anywhere, so you could as well have everything crammed in one single line ie:

```
{"users":[{"name":"test"},{"name":"test2"}]}
```

wrt/ memory comsuption / perfs etc, json is not designed for huge datasets anyway (you want jsonlines or something similar for this) so you shouldn't worry about it - and that's your only option anyway.

Comment: For me it was complicated yes, because im learning Python and touching json the first time in my life. Isn't it bad to load the file and its content every time to parse them back then? What if i have for example 9999 Items in the "user" list. Isn't there a method to just append an item to the list without store the entire json file into a variable ? I read something about `open('jsonfile', 'a') for appending ?

Comment: @Luranis cf my edited answer. TL;DR : no there's no other solution with json, and if it gets so huge it becomes a problem then json is not the right format for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```
import json
# your string
json_string = '{
    "users":
      [
        {"name" : "test"},
        {"name" : "test2"}
      ]
    }'
# convert it to a python dictionary
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
# append your data as {key:value}
json_dict['users'].append({'name':'test3'})
# convert it back to string
json_string = json.dumps(json_dict)
print (json_string)
```